# How to access k3d Kubernetes cluster from inside a docker container?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have a running k3d Kubernetes cluster:

```
$ kubectl cluster-info
Kubernetes master is running at https://0.0.0.0:6550
CoreDNS is running at https://0.0.0.0:6550/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns:dns/proxy
Metrics-server is running at https://0.0.0.0:6550/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/https:metrics-server:/proxy
```

I have a python script that uses the kubernetes client api and manages namespaces, deployments, pod, etc. This works just fine in my local environment because I have all the necessary python modules installed and have direct access to my local k8s cluster. My goal is to containerize so that this same script is successfully run for my colleagues on their systems.

While running the same python script in a docker container, I receive connection errors:

```
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='172.17.0.1', port=6550): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v1/namespaces (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f8b637c5d68>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 113] No route to host',))
```

`172.17.0.1` is my `docker0` bridge address so assumed that would resolve or forward traffic to my localhost. I have tried loading k8s configuration from my local `.kube/config` which references `server: https://0.0.0.0:6550` and also creating a separate config file with `server: https://172.17.0.1:6550` and both give the same `No route to host` error (with the respective ip address in the HTTPSConnectionPool(host=...))

One idea I was pursing was running a socat process outside the container and tunnel traffic from inside the container across a bridge socket mounted in from the outside, but looks like the docker image I need to use does not have socat installed. However, I get the feeling like the real solution should be much simplier than all of this.

Certainly there have been other instances of a docker container needing access to a k8s cluster served outside of the docker network. How is this connection typically established?

Answer (score 0):

Use `docker network` command to create a predefined network

You can pass `--network` to attach k3d to an existing Docker network and also to `docker run` to do the same for another container

https://k3d.io/internals/networking/